# Set to 2 decimals for integer in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to calculate a total price depending on a users input, but I am experiencing the floating point syndrome. I have checked several other answers, but cannot make it work on my own code.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("select").change(function () {
        var adultTicketsSubtotal = 0;
        var adultPrice = $("#price-adult").data("price");
        $("#ticket-select-adult").each(function () {
            adultTicketsSubtotal = adultPrice * parseInt($(this).val()).toFixed(2);
        })
        $("#adult-total .total").html(adultTicketsSubtotal);
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("#ticket-select-adult").each` - erm, what? You should only have a single item in your DOM with specific ID, those supposed to be unique.

Comment: The error is elsewhere. Your code, as is, [works](https://jsfiddle.net/vx6m17hf/1/).

Comment: Just `$("#ticket-select-adult").val()`. Or drop that construct and handle that as in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
$(function() {
  var $subtotalView = $("#adult-total .total");
  var adultPrice = parseFloat( $("#price-adult").data("price") );
  // TODO: handle NaN case somehow: what if server sets this incorrectly?

  $('#ticket-select-adult').change(function() {
    var ticketsCount = parseInt( this.value, 10 );
    var subtotal = isNaN(ticketsCount) ? 
      ' n/a ' : 
      (ticketsCount * adultPrice).toFixed(2);
    $subtotalView.text(subtotal);
  });
});
```

Several minor changes here: the DOM traversals are minimized, `this.value` replaces `$(this).val()` etc. What's important is type fixation: `adultPrice` is *always* a float, `ticketsCount` always an int (or NaN for placeholder values, but this case is handled), and `subtotal` is always a string of the given format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the .toFixed() method like:

```
$("#adult-total .total").html(adultTicketsSubtotal.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

In place of parseInt , Use parseFloat . Do multiplication and then use toFixed

parseInt changes the number to an integer.

```
adultTicketsSubtotal = (adultPrice * (parseFloat($(this).val()))).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: But overall, it's a correct approach - just a part of it. One has to write the answer that combines `parseFloat`-ing the values and `toFixed(2)` the cumulative result. )

Comment: hmm... you are still performing math operations between two strings, but JS is smart enough to convert them to numbers. Guess that's good enough.

Comment: Of course, with `*` (and all the math ops but `+`, that one's overloaded) both operands are cast to Numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
adultTicketsSubtotal = adultPrice.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
```

Comment: Nice, but not supported in WebKit (=iOS Safari).

Comment: Maybe a library for use something like toLocaleString() on safari would be the solution.